# Tortoise and the Hare, pointers example C

Tags: c

The code works, but it wont complete unless both the tortoise and the hare finish. My question is trying to get it so either the hare finishes or the turtle does and ends the program.

Below is the question, I've added it because I couldn't post if it wasn't there because I have "too much code."

This is the question:
The Tortoise and the Hare: In this problem, you’ll recreate one of the truly
great moments in history, namely the classic race of the tortoise and the hare. You’ll use random number generation to develop a simulation of this memorable event.
Our contenders begin the race at “square 1” of 70 squares. Each square represents a possible position along the race course. The finish line is at square 70. The first contender to reach or pass square 70 is rewarded with a pail of fresh carrots and lettuce. The course weaves its way up the side of a slippery mountain, so occasionally the contenders lose ground.
There’s a clock that ticks once per second. With each tick of the clock, your program should adjust the position of the animals

[code/]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define FINISH 70

// function calls for pointer to hare and tortiose and positioning

void position1 ( int* tPtr );
void position2 ( int* hPtr );
void printPositions ( int* tPtr , int* hPtr );


int main (void)
{

    int turtle = 1, hare = 1, movement1 = 1, movement2 = 1, timer = 0, start = 0; // variables
    int choice; // Exit choice
    int *tPtr = &turtle; // tort pointer
    int *hPtr = &hare; // hare pointer

    printf ( "To have the tortiose and the hare race, press 1 [Any other character to exit]: " );
    scanf ( "%d", &start ); // input to start

    while ( start == 1 )
    {

        puts ( "BANG!!!!!!" );
        puts ( "AND THEY'RE OFF!!!!!" );
        puts ( "HT" );
        // for loop to activate this function call to 70.
//        printf ( "%d %d ", *tPtr, *hPtr);
        for ( turtle != FINISH, hare != FINISH; turtle <= 70 || hare <= 70; timer++ )
        {
            sleep(1);
            position1 ( &turtle );     //function call tort
            position2 ( &hare );    // fucntion call hare
            printPositions ( &turtle, &hare ); // function call print result
//            printf ( "%d %d", *tPtr, *hPtr);
        }

        if ( hare >= FINISH || turtle >= FINISH ) // results
        {
            if ( turtle > hare )
            {
                printf ( "THE TORTIOSE WINS!!!!\n" );
                printf ( "The race took: %ds\n", timer );
            }

            else if ( hare > turtle )
            {
                printf ( "The hare wins. Yuch\n" );
                printf ( "The race took: %ds\n", timer );
            }

            else
            {
                printf ( "Tie race!\n" );
                printf ( "The race took: %ds\n", timer );
            }

        }// end results

    break; // stops while loop (No exit condition)
    } // end main while loop


} // end main

void position1 ( int *tPtr ) // function call for tortoise
{

    int turtle;

        srand( time ( 0 ));
        turtle = 1 + ( rand() % 10 ) ;
    //    printf ( "%d ", turtle );
    //    printf( "%d", *tPtr );

        if ( turtle >= 1 || turtle <= 5 )// movement1 <=5
        {
            *tPtr += 3;
        //    printf ( "m3t ");
        }
        else if ( turtle == 6 || turtle == 7 ) // movement1 = 6 && movement1 = 7
        {
            *tPtr -= 6;
        //    printf ( " m-6t ");
        }
        else if ( turtle >= 8 ) // movement1 >=8
        {
            *tPtr += 1;
        //    printf ( "m1t ");
        }

        else // (movement1 < 1 )
        {
            *tPtr == 1;
        //    printf ( "m0t ");
        }
}// end of turtle fucntion

void position2 ( int *hPtr ) // function call for hare
{

    int hare;

        srand (time ( 0 ));
        hare = 1 + ( rand() % 10 );
    //    printf ( "%d ", *hPtr);

        if ( hare <= 2)// movement2 <=2
        {
            *hPtr += 1;
        //    printf ( "m1h ");
        }

        else if ( hare == 3 || hare == 4 ) // movement2 = 6 && movement2 = 7
        {
            *hPtr = *hPtr;
        //    printf ( "m0h ");
        }

        else if ( hare >= 5 || hare <= 7 ) // movement2 >=8
        {
            *hPtr += 9;
        //    printf ( "m9h ");
        }

        else if ( hare >= 8 || hare <= 9 )
        {
            *hPtr -= 2;
        //    printf ( "m-2h ");
        }

        else if ( hare == 10 )// (movement2 < 1 )
        {
            *hPtr -= 12;
        //    printf ( "m-12h  " );
        }
        else
        {
            *hPtr = 1;
        }
}// end of turtle fucntion

void printPositions ( int *tPtr, int *hPtr ) // Race Print function start
{
    int movement;
    int turtle;
    int hare;

    if ( &turtle == &hare ) // We are only getting in here, why?
    {
    //    printf ( " *tPtr == *hPtr ");
        for ( movement = 0; movement < *tPtr; movement++ )
            {
                printf ( " " );
            }
        printf ( "OUCH!" );
    }
    else if ( *tPtr < *hPtr )
    {
        //printf( "*tPtr < *hPtr " );
        for ( movement = 0; movement < *tPtr; movement++ )
            printf ( " " );

        printf ( "T" );


        for ( movement = 0; movement < (*hPtr - *tPtr); movement++ )
            printf ( " " );

        printf ( "H" );
    }

    else
    {
        //printf ( " *hptr < *tptr " );
        for ( movement = 0; movement < *hPtr; movement++)
        {
            printf ( " " );
        }
        printf ( "H" );
        for (movement = 0; movement < ( *tPtr - *hPtr ); movement++ )
        {
            printf ( " " );
        }
        printf ( "T" );
    }
    printf ( "\n" );


} // race print function, end.
```

[/code]

Comment: Aside: call `srand (time ( 0 ));` *once* in `main` and delete every other.

Comment: I tried to after you mentioned this, but it created a problem where turtle was always between 1 and 5

Comment: Whatever, `srand` does not create problems. It seeds the PRNG once, typically at the start of the program. That is how to use `srand`. You may have other problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the culprit:

```
for ( turtle != FINISH, hare != FINISH; turtle <= 70 || hare <= 70; timer++ )
```

This is your initialization of the while loop:

```
turtle != FINISH, hare != FINISH;
```

These are boolean expressions and thus essentially no-ops. It should usually initialize your loop variables, for example

```
turtle = 1, hare = 1;
```

This is your loop condition:

```
turtle <= 70 || hare <= 70;
```

It is true, while the turtle is not in the finish *or* the hare is not in the finish. You seem to want a boolean *and* here (and better use the macro FINISH you defined):

```
turtle < FINISH && hare < finish;
```

There are several other issues, but that addresses the question you asked.

Comment: I've changed the variables and changed it to a while loop, it fixed my issue.

Were there many other mistakes you were talking about?